# Insert into a table using tdbrow talend -casting datatype or conversion issues?

Tags: java, oracle, insert, talend, dml

Tdbrow:
In the brackets i have indicated their predefined datatype in the table!

```
insert into FILETABLE
      (ID (number), DIR(number), file_name(varchar2), file_date(date),file_size(number))
    values
      (file_seq.nextval,
       '"+((String)globalMap.get("DIRID"))+"',
       '"+((String)globalMap.get("FILE_NAME"))+"',
       to_date('"+context.FILE_DATE+"','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
       '"+((String)globalMap.get("FILE_SIZE"))+"')
```

The values for the global & context variables are obtained in the previous step through tjavarow.

For DATE alone i am trying to use context variable to avoid confusion,but for some reason it wont work at all and i keep getting ORA error's like invalid number etc.

```
context.FILE_DATE=2021-01-28 10:22:41 (This is the stored value)
```

and when inserting into the db the desired format is as such:

```
 to_date(i_file_date,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

#1.I am able to handle strings and varchar2 from java onto the oracle databse.
#2.The real concern here is for the number datatype which is extracted as Integer in java (still wont work) and keeps throwing error
#3.How to handle DATE from java and therein inserting into oracle database in the desired format.

Thanks for your help![enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/veVHg.png

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have your date format reversed, the format you supply is to tell Oracle how to convert the given string into Oracle internal date datatype you have now control over how it is stored and it does not really concern you at this time.
You should use

```
to_date('"+context.FILE_DATE+"','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),
```

If you need to read your date back in the format indicated you can use:

```
to_char(file_date,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

Or you can set the NLS_DATE_FORMAT variable or configure your environment to use that format as default.

You probably should also read up on using bind variables, it is a lot saver and it knows how to handle casting from Java datatypes into Oracle datatypes.